# Can I create new associations that don't exist in the model in Factory Girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, factory-bot

I'm writing test for a model written by someone else.  The child model has a belongs_to but the parent model does not have a has_many.

Can I create a has_many in Factory Girl for my own purposes even though it doesn't exist in the model?